# I am trying to write this function which gives the added value of the squares of 2 of the biggest numeric values

Tags: r

I tried this question on R programming but for some reason, my code doesn't seem to work. Could someone please explain where I'm wrong? Thanks.

```
largenumbers <- function(d,e,f) {
  if{d==e & e==f & f==d}
  print("Please provide different numbers")
  else{
  Largest <- max(c(d,e,f))
  SecondLargest <- max(c(d,e,f)[-which.max(c(d,e,f))])
  return(Largest^2 + SecondLargest^2)
  }
}

largenumbers(4,5,6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the syntax issue with `if`, I think you also have a logical issue. Instead of `&` the condition should be `|` (or even better `||` as the values are scalar) to avoid any duplicate value.

You may also use `sort`, then select last 2 values and return sum of squares.

```
largenumbers <- function(d,e,f) {
  if(d==e || e==f || f==d)
  stop("Please provide different numbers")
  else{
    num <- sort(c(d, e, f))
    return(sum(tail(num, 2)^2))
  }
}

largenumbers(4,5,6)
#[1] 61

largenumbers(10, 12, 6)
#[1] 244

largenumbers(10, 12, 12)
```

> Error in largenumbers(10, 12, 12) : Please provide different numbers

Answer (score 3):

```
if (condition) {
  do
} else {
  do
}
```

in your function, problem is  `if{d==e & e==f & f==d}`. It should be `if(d==e & e==f & f==d)`. Formal version is

```
largenumbers <- function(d,e,f) {
  if(d==e & e==f & f==d){
  print("Please provide different numbers")}
  else{
    Largest <- max(c(d,e,f))
    SecondLargest <- max(c(d,e,f)[-which.max(c(d,e,f))])
    return(Largest^2 + SecondLargest^2)
  }
}
largenumbers(4,5,6)
[1] 61
```